# How do Prefix lists factor into the permission entry limit in Security Groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have added 7 inbound rules, 5 of them are with "Managed prefix list" that has 2 entries, those entries are public IPs with /32 CIDR block, so I am not able to add more inbound rules with "pl" as the max count gets reached, but how the figure "52" is calculated ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you reference a prefix list in a resource, **the maximum number of entries for the prefix lists counts against the quota for the number of entries for the resource**. For example, if you create a prefix list with 20 maximum entries and you reference that prefix list in a security group rule, this counts as 20 security group rules.
>
> — [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/managed-prefix-lists.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20reference,security%20group%20rules.), emphasis mine

**tl;dr:** You define a max length for each prefix list that's taken into account when the number of (inbound) rules is calculated.

Comment: I just realized that by playing with it